# How to add Anchor Tags To Jump To Specific Location from page to another page

Tags: html, anchor

I want to use **Anchor Tag** for jump to relevant section of a page but i want to done this jump from any page for example WORK.html page(by menu). 
I have a menu that there is in all pages. i want with click on any option, jump to relevant section but when am in another pages too.

such as this image: [menu image!](http://uupload.ir/files/iphg_m.jpg)

in the image, I want to go from WORK page to Scaffolding or Typography that are on a single page.
this code is in menu codes in WORK.html:

```
    <a href="STYLE.html">go to relevant section</a>
```

but should instead of "STYLE.html" jump to relevant section from "STYLE.html"

how to done this work???

Comment: this is called bookmarks, each item you want to jump to must have a known ID, see @Antonio's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an id to the div regarding the relevant part of your page. So put this preceded by the symbol id # at the end of the page link.

For example:

```
<a href="STYLE.html#myRelevantSectionId">go to relevant section</a>
```